# Delete Row+3 which contains word without loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet which contains 4 general lines constant in every quote. Depending on the # of line items in the quote the rows where these 4 general lines occur varies. I am trying to find a code which locates the words "SHOP TICKETS" in column B and then deletes that row and the 3 below it without containing a loop. The loop is not needed and seems to bog it down. I have been at this for 2 days, and I can't seem to find the right code.

I've tried For Each, With, Find, a whole bunch of solutions I have found online, but none seem to work right. except a Dim one but it slowed it down so much it wasn't worth keeping. I'm new/self taught so please be patient with me.

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54132677/edit) to give us  the code you have so far?

Comment: Do those words only happen once per quote?

Comment: This is not a coding service where you state your requirements and get back ready-to-run debugged code. 
You need to put in some efforts yourself. Show us your code.
Also read Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:
**https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve**

Comment: I don't know what code to use. I have tried so many. Do you want me to share them all? I did not think this was a code service, and as I said I have been putting in effort for 2 days trying to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub delete
   With WorkSheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your sheet
       Dim rw as Long
       On Error Resume Next
           rw = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("SHOP TICKETS",.Range("B:B"),0)
       On Error Goto 0

       If rw > 0 Then
           .Range(rw & ":" & rw + 3).entirerow.delete
       End if
    End with
 End sub
```

Comment: I tried this one and got back a Run-time Error '9': Subscript out of range.  I tried recording a macro but it sets the rows to delete as fixed and they move around. I don't know how to fix

Comment: Range("A15").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(2, 0).Select
    Set rng = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 0))
    rng.EntireRow.Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    With Range("B15:B500")
        .Value = .Value
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    Cells.Find(What:="SHOP TICKETS", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Rows("68:71").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

Comment: i also don't know how to post my code without it being all jumbled. Im sorry. but this one starts here. Cells.Find(What:="SHOP TICKETS", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _ LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _ MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate Rows("68:71").Select Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

Comment: I was missing an `&`.  but otherwise it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cells.Find(What:="SHOP TICKETS", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Set rng = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0))
rng.EntireRow.Delete
```

I got it!! Thanks. Talking it through to a group helped.